# How to see/retrieve the note/message that was sent to notify the recipient while sharing a google drive folder?

Tags: google-drive

I shared a Google drive folder to a professor. While sharing the folder, I had an option to send a message/note. I added a message but I want to check what I sent. Someone had suggested to activate "send a copy to myself" before sharing and sending the note. However there is no such option to tick "send a copy to myself."[image]